# error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Accessor/RuntimeRootNode

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

this error appearing me when build the app on release mode and linking on SDKonly

I think this error happens because I add firebase notification plugins and added the plugin.fingerprint or because updated all plugins on app

I tried  to set linking on none but appearing me another error,
the error is after build and archives the app and when install the app on device appearing my error (the application is not installed

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Accessor/RuntimeRootNode::.ctor(Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlType,System.Xml.IXmlNamespaceResolver)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Loader.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode::.ctor(Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlType,System.Xml.IXmlNamespaceResolver)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   Almond.Droid
```